# I have a question about c programming using While

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(n>0) {
        printf("%d ", n);
        n--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this command work when the while conditional sentence is (n==0)?

Comment: becouse `n==0` makes the condition `n>0` be false. If you want that your loop run with `n==0`, change the condition to `n>=0`

Comment: because of the condition `(n > 0)` returns false

Comment: Hey Jis! Welcome to SO. Please always do a quick google search before asking a question here. You can follow some tutorials for such kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

`while(condition)` cycle runs, as its name proposes, **while** the condition is True (or non zero in C). As soon, as it becomes False (or 0), the cycle is aborted. If you place `n==0` as a condition, the cycle is aborted right away. You can change this by typing `while(n != 0)`, or `while(!(n==0))`

Answer (score 0):

The operator > excludes the number itself. Use >= if you want it to work with the number you are using as operand